# AWS application load balancer not forwarding requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an application load balancer with a HTTP listener that should be invoking a Lambda.

[image: Listener settings]

However, there is no response when I make a request to the ALB's endpoint (`This site can’t be reached`).

There is no logs in Lambda's Cloudwatch from the requests I'm making, so it seems doesn't get invoked.

I also enabled Access Logs for ALB, however the bucket only contains one file (`AWSLogs/ELBAccessLogTestFile`) that was created when logging was enabled.

Additionally, I enabled health checks on the Target Group, and it's showing that the target Lambda is healthy. I can see the health check requests in Lambda's CloudWatch.

[image]

ACL allows all traffic:

[image: ACL settings]

There are 3 subnets associated with the ALB, they all use the same route table that does link to Internet Gateway:

[image: Route table settings]

So to me it looks like everything that's mentioned in the [AWS troubleshooting for ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#client-cannot-connect) is fine.

---

---

---

Other relevant settings:

[image]

Comment: Is you ALB internet-facing, and if not do you try to reach it from inside the VPC? Does the SG associated to your ALB allow for connection? If you curl the IP of the ALB directly (see your Network Interfaces), can you reach the Lambda?

Comment: @Mornor SG allows all traffic, all protocols on all ports. ALB does say `Scheme: internet-facing`. I'm not trying to reach it from inside the VPC, but from the internet. VPC has the associated route table I put in the question post.  I tried to curl all IPs for the 3 Elastic Network Interfaces and I get `Failed to connect to <> port 80: Timed out` for all. I get the same when curling `http://openeo-dev-<some-id>.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/`.

Comment: Is your Lambda deployed in a VPC, and if yes, does the SG associated to it allow connections from the SG attached to the ALB?

Comment: Also, did you allow the Lambda function to be called by your ALB, as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html)?

Comment: @Mornor No, Lambda is not in a VPC.

I believe the permission for invoking Lambda from ALB was added automatically when I created the target group. And that works given health checks work. 

I added an image in the OP with other relevant settings.

Answer (score 3):

> Failed to connect to <> port 80: Timed out

This message indicates that the curl can't connect to the ALB, not the ALB to lambda. Your ACL and route table look good. So I'd suggest checking a security group of the ALB. It must allow traffic on port 80 from at least your IP (or from specific CIDR depending on your requirements).

Comment: Security group allows all traffic. I added screenshots of other relevant settings in the OP.

Comment: This was exactly it for me. Possibly something else for the OP, but those screenshots still don't show how that security group was associated with the ALB.

Comment: The default security group allows traffic from other resources in the same group, but not traffic from the Internet. You need to add an inbound rule with a source of Anywhere-IPv4 or Anywhere-IPv6.